# Creating Excel-like table in vb.NET

Tags: vb.net

Basically, I want to display a matrix whose size is the number of columns and rows specified by the user. This matrix will be editable like a spreadsheet to allow for numbers to be entered in each cell.

**The problem:** I don't know how to create such matrix in vb.NET.

Comment: I'll echo others. It's not a code writing service. You must ask a specific question. Look into DataGrids and samples

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks for your comment but maybe you should read my problem. I never asked for code, just need direction into something that might work for the parameters given. I don't think I can be more specific into what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the WinForm control: `DataGridView`?

At design time or programmatically during runtime, you can add and remove columns and rows.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I saw it but someone had told me that was for databases only. But after removing headers for both columns and rows it actually looks like what I am looking for. The only issue I see is that it keeps adding rows which I don't want. Should be trivial enough to make the table static, right?

Comment: It's easy to work with between databases, but it can be used to fill and display just about any data. You can limit how many rows it has. Add an event handler for adding a row and if the current row count is your limit, exit the handler. You can also disable adding rows through the grid itself. You can enable/disable edit-mode. In the designer, when you drag the DataGridView onto your form, select it and familiarize yourself with some of the properties. There are tons of options available.